# What are the common myths associated with Artificial Intelligence?

Tags: philosophy, agi, mythology-of-ai

What are some interesting myths of Artificial Intelligence and what are the facts behind them?

Comment: Hi and welcome to AI Stack Exchange. Sadly this is not a fit to the site format. It would be a great question on a forum, but this is not a forum. If you could re-phrase the question so that it could have an objective single answer, then it would fit. That might work if you asked about a single rumour/myth that you had seen somewhere and wanted to know the truth behind it.

Answer (score 6):

As Artificial Intelligence is rapidly invading in our lives the myths around AI is also fabricating rapidly. Before getting into details one need to get clear off from this myths.

**Myth 1: AI will take away our jobs:**

**Reality:** AI is not completely different from other technologies and AI will not take away jobs but AI will change the way we work and helps us to increase the productivity by removing monotonous works.

**Myth 2: Artificial intelligence will take over the world:**

**Reality:** AI controlling the world. According to me it will not possible unless we give it that power. AI or robots will assist in our work and helps us to solve some tedious works that are difficult for human to solve easily.

**Myth 3: Intelligent machines can learn on their own**

**Reality:** It seems that a Intelligent machine can learn by it own. But the fact is that a AI Engineer or AI specialist should develop the algorithm and feed the machine with datasets and instructions and continuous monitoring should be done and most importantly regular update of software should be done.

**Myth 4: Artificial Intelligence, Machine learning and Deep learning all three are same:**

**Reality:** No not at all. To be clear machine learning is a part of AI and deep learning is the subset of ML. All three- AL, ML and DL are different but they are inter related with each other.

Comment: _unless we give it that power_ I wonder how many powerful governments or organizations would just _love_ to give an AI the power to control the world on their behalf...

Answer (score 2):

In artificial intelligence, even though not everyone agrees, a common (and maybe the biggest) myth is that of the [intelligence explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technological_singularity), which some people claim will happen (without considering physical limits or knowing anything about thermodynamics).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105330/discussion-on-answer-by-nbro-what-are-the-common-myths-associated-with-artificia).